# a.e. convergence of a piecewise constant function $f_h(t)=\left\lfloor \frac{t}{h} \right\rfloor \cdot h$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $$f_h(t)=\left\lfloor \frac{t}{h} \right\rfloor \cdot h \qquad \text{ and } \qquad f(t) =t$$
Is it true that $$f_h \stackrel{h \to 0}{\longrightarrow} f \ \text{ a.e. ? }$$
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $(t/h-1)h<f_h(t)\le(t/h)h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\frac{t}{h}-1)h\leq f_h(t)\leq \frac{t}{h}h$ is immediate as a property of the floor function. This reduces to $t-h\leq f_h(t)\leq t$ so by the squeeze theorem, we are done.

Comment: This appears to work for every value, not almost every value.

Comment: The convergence is uniform. Just find a bound for $|t-f_h(t)|$.